# Can it be shown that for numbers $n_L$ of the form 166...661 of length L, if $n_L$ is prime then $L$ is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The first 8 primes of the form 166...661 have lengths 5, 13, 17, 19, 37, 53, 73, and 101. It is always the case if a number of this form is prime then its length also must be prime?

Comment: Note that $$n_L=\frac{5\cdot10^{L-1}-17}3$$

Comment: Have not found a probable prime checking up to 4000 digits. It may be the case that these are the only prime values of the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org/A082700),

the next (probable) prime of that form has $6233$ digits,

and $6233=23×271$.

Comment: the next primes after that have $24029$ (prime), $40223 (19\times29\times73)$, and $66395 (5\times7^2\times271)$ digits

Comment: If these probable primes are correct then this information answers the question...

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even, the number is divisible by $11$.
If $n$ is odd and divisible by $3$, the number is divisible by $7$.
That leaves $33$ possible $n$, of which $24$ are prime.
If you picked eight of the 33 at random, you would have $5.3\%$ chance of getting all prime.  Can you get some more data ?

Comment: division by 13 starts remainder 10 before alternating 2,6 taken first 3 digits at a time. not sure what happens at the far end.

Comment: See some additional known [periodic factors](https://stdkmd.net/nrr/1/16661.htm#prime)