# For a given $a$, for which values of $b$ and $c$ is the sequence $\frac{a\cdot10^n-b}{c}$ guaranteed to return integer terms with GCD=1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, repunit-numbers

One example are the [repunits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3138191/primes-with-digits-only-1) where $a=1$, $b=1$, and $c=9$. Another [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462941/are-there-an-infinite-number-of-primes-of-the-form-133-331) are the numbers of the form 133...331 which are generated by the values $a=4$, $b=7$, and $c=3$. There are [lots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462981/can-it-be-shown-that-for-numbers-n-l-of-the-form-166-661-of-length-l-if-n) of other [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226024/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-form-underbrace3-dots3-n1?noredirect=1&lq=1). Is there a way to determine for a given value of $a$ which values are always guaranteed to return an integer?

Comment: Did you mean $a=1$ for repunits?

Comment: It works when always $a\cdot10^n\equiv b\pmod c$, which holds for the examples you gave because $a\equiv b$ and $10\equiv 1\pmod c$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I guess what we are really after is when the values of a,b,c return integer terms which do not always share a set of factors? So in some sense they are in 'lowest terms' and it makes it possible to ask when they are prime... I edited the question to be more restrictive.